# how to change default MarkLogic log to different location

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

The Marklogic logs default path /var/opt/MarkLogic/Logs. How to setup in /etc/marklogic.conf to change Logs to different location.

in /etc/marklogic.conf

```
  MARKLOGIC_INSTALL_DIR=/opt/MarkLogic
  MARKLOGIC_DATA_DIR=/var/opt/MarkLogic
  MARKLOGIC_FSTYPE=ext4
  MARKLOGIC_USER=raymond
  MARKLOGIC_PID_FILE=/var/run/MarkLogic.pid
  MARKLOGIC_UMASK=022
```

Comment: I've always used a soft link

Comment: Yes. the Log directory is not configurable separately from the Data directory. ( == "$MARKLOGIC_DATA_DIR/Logs" ).
mv -f  $MARKLOGIC_DATA_DIR/Logs;
ln -s REAL_LOG_DIR $MARKLOGIC_DATA_DIR/Logs

or 
 mount -B REAL_LOG_DIR $MARKLOGIC_DATA_DIR/Logs